# Set global constant cross all the view

Tags: python, django

This sounds nasty. I want to set a global variable in the request, which means all my views can refer to that constant by doing:

```
getattr(request, 'CONSTANT_NAME', None)
```

However, this variable's value may be changed at some point, which means I have the following code in one of my view:

```
setattr(request, 'CONSTANT_NAME', VALUE)
```

I know the way I am doing this is definitely wrong, but I wish to know if there is a correct and clean way to achieve what I am looking for.

I am thinking about middleware, but not sure how to do it. A hint is sufficient.

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE:
Someone mentioned about Session. I pretty sure it should works. However, it is not clean enough. By using session, I need to create same constant as many times as the total number of sessions server maintaining. In fact, the constant remain the same cross the server and it has to be mutable! The last requirement is the nasty part.

Comment: Have you tried Django Sessions?  Here's the link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#bundled-serializers  This let's you get and set variables to the session.  Alternatively, you could use a context_processor to use global variables accross views.

Comment: The best approach really depends on what the value is meant to represent and how it is used. If it is meant to be associated with a session, then you add it to the session object. If it is something else, you might need a different solution.

Comment: @AronYsidoro Session is my last bet. The reason I don't want to use it is that my variable is not session specific, it is server specific. Session shall works, but not clean enough. Context processor is not option. I don't think I alter the value provide by context processor

Comment: @Louis, please take a look at the response I gave to AronYsidoro. Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely go with Middleware then.  This chapter on Middleware is useful in the DjangoBook: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter17.html

Comment: How about django.core.cache ? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @AdelaN,I have taken the way of middleware, which eventually works. Cache is not a feasible solution since I am not caching anything but setting a global mutable constant. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I took the way of Middleware. I wrote a custom middleware and set a variable in the middleware, something like,

```
CONSTANT_NAME = None
```

It is global.
And a local thread:

```
_thread_local = threading.local()
```

which is also global.

Then I have two methods in the middleware,

```
def get_constant_value()
    return getattr(_thread_local, 'CONSTANT_NAME', None)

def set_constant_value(value):
    CONSTANT_NAME = value
```

which can be called from any views.

Then inside my middleware, I have

```
def process_request(self, request):
    _thread_local.CONSTANT_NAME = CONSTANT_NAME
```

At this point, I call set and get this server-crossed variable from any view I want.

The solution is not perfect (I believe). If anyone got a better idea, let me know please!

Thanks!